# Showing $1+\cos(\theta)+\dots+\cos (n\theta)=\frac12+\frac{\sin((n+\frac12)\theta)}{2\sin(\frac\theta2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Suppose that $n \geq 1$ is a natural number.
>
> (i) Show that for $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$, provided $z \neq 1$,
>
> $$ \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} = 1+z+...+z^n.$$
>
> (ii) Using de Moivre’s Theorem, part (b)(i) and standard trigonometric identities, show that for $\theta$ in $(0,2\pi)$,
>
> $$ 1+\cos(\theta) + \dots + \cos (n\theta) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin((n+\frac12)\theta)}{2\sin(\frac\theta2)}$$

I have set $z=a+bi$ and subbed this into the top equation but dont seem to be getting anwhere with this problem. Any guidance will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From part (i), for $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{1\},$
$$1+z+...+z^n=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}.$$

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $\theta\in(0,2\pi).$ Then
$$1+e^{i\theta}+...+e^{in\theta} = \frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\\
=\frac{e^{i\frac{n+1}2\theta}\left[e^{-i\frac{n+1}2\theta}-e^{i\frac{n+1}2\theta}\right]}{e^{i\frac\theta2}\left[e^{-i\frac\theta2}-e^{i\frac\theta2}\right]}\\
\color{#C00}{\overset1=}e^{i\frac{n}2\theta}\frac{-2i\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{-2i\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)}\\
=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)}e^{i\frac{n}2\theta}.$$

By Euler's formula and equating real parts,
$$ 1+\cos(\theta) + \dots + \cos (n\theta) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)}\cos\left(\frac{n}2\theta\right) \\
\color{#C00}{\overset2=} \frac1{\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)}{\frac12\left[\sin\left(\left(n+\frac12\right)\theta\right)+\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)\right]} \\
= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin\left(\left(n+\frac12\right)\theta\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)}.\\$$

<sup>1</sup> using $e^{i\alpha}-e^{-i\alpha}=2i\sin(\alpha)$

<sup>2</sup> using one of the product-to-sum trigonometric identities

Answer (score 1):

Part (i) should be straightforward if you are familiar with finding the sum of a geometric series:
\begin{align}
S &= 1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^{n-1}+z^n \\
zS &= z+z^2+z^3+\ldots + z^n+z^{n+1} \\
zS - S &= z^{n+1}-1 \\
S(z-1) &= z^{n+1}-1 \\
S &= \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1} = \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} \, . \\ 
\end{align}
For part (ii), you should first consider the geometric series
$$
1+e^{i\theta}+e^{2i\theta}+\ldots+e^{ni\theta} \, .
$$
Since $e^{ik\theta}=\cos k\theta+i\sin k\theta$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we know that
\begin{align}
&1+e^{i\theta}+e^{2i\theta}+\ldots+e^{ni\theta}\\=&1+(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+(\cos 2\theta+i\sin 2\theta)+\ldots+(\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta)
\end{align}
Hence,
$$
1+\cos\theta+\cos 2\theta+\ldots+\cos n \theta=\Re(1+e^{i\theta}+e^{2i\theta}+\ldots+e^{ni\theta}) \, .
$$

Comment: You don't explain how to obtain the RHS....

Comment: @JeanMarie: I don't know which part of my answer you are referring to. Is it possible if you point out which line I should elaborate about?

Comment: I mean: how do you obtain $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin((n+1/2)\theta)}{2\sin(\theta/2)}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: My goal was to merely give OP a hint for solving that part of the question, and not to do the rest for them. If my answer is too terse, then thankfully user2661923 has outlined a more detailed approach.

Answer (score 1):

Hints guides

Breaking $z$ into $(x + iy)$ is **bad** for these particular problems.

Part (i) 
multiply the denominator by the RHS.

Part (ii) 
This one, which happens to be part of my Complex Analysis textbook, is **really** no walk in the park.  Need introductory identities.

$\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b).$ 
$\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a).$

$\sin \,a  ~-~ \sin \,b ~=~ 
2\,\sin\left(\frac{a - b}{2}\right) \times 
\cos\left(\frac{a + b}{2}\right) \implies $

$\sin [(n + 1)\theta] ~-~ \sin \,(n\theta)
~=~
2 \,\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \times
\cos \left[\frac{(2n + 1)\theta}{2}\right].$

$\cos \,a  ~-~ \cos \,b ~=~
- 2 \,\sin\left(\frac{a - b}{2}\right) \times 
\sin\left(\frac{a + b}{2}\right) \implies $

$\cos (n\theta) ~-~ \cos \,[(n + 1)\theta] ~=~ 
2 \,\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \times
\sin \left[\frac{(2n + 1)\theta}{2}\right].$

Let $\;A ~\equiv ~ \sum_{k = 0}^n
        (\cos \,k\theta ~+~ i \,\sin \,k\theta).$

Let $\displaystyle\;B ~\equiv ~ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) ~+~
\left\{\frac{\sin \,\left[\frac{(2n + 1)\theta}{2}\right]}
{2 \,\sin \,(\theta/2)}\right\}.$

Let $\displaystyle\;C ~\equiv ~ 
\left(\frac{\cot (\theta/2)}{2}\right) ~-~
\left\{\frac{\cos \,\left[\frac{(2n + 1)\theta}{2}\right]}
{2 \,\sin \,(\theta/2)}\right\}.$

**To Show:** $\,A ~=~ B + iC.$

---

It is assumed that $(2\pi)$ does not divide $(\theta)$.

Use part (1), substituting $e^{i\theta}$ for $z$, to
re-express $A$.

Simplify $A$ to $\frac{R + iS}{T}$ and then prove that
$B = \frac{R}{T}, C = \frac{S}{T}.$

If you wish to use this answer, and encounter questions or roadblocks, edit your query to show all of your work,
and leave very explicit questions as a comment following this
*answer*.

I will automatically be flagged.  For your comment/questions,
try to have the detailed preliminary work done in your query, and
then ask very specific questions, like:

- "In my query, expression (1) signifies $\frac{R}{T}$ and expression (2) signifies $B$.  
  How do I show that
  expression (1) = expression (2)"?